# Configuring haproxy to migrate users from one backend to another

Tags: haproxy

I have a service which clients connect to using TCP. Currently there are 14 instances of this service, which are load-balanced by haproxy. Users on the internet connect to this service, and I have no control over the user's hardware which connects to this service.

The daemon which runs the service has been rewritten, and what I want to achieve is having a small number of users connect to the new daemon, leaving the rest of the users on the old version. I want to be able to control which clients connect to the new daemon (we know which IP ranges clients will be connecting from).

Once a client has connected to the new daemon, we don't want them to connect to the old daemon.

So I guess what we want to do is have haproxy choose a specific backend, for clients connecting to the front-end from a specific range.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

We are currently using haproxy 1.5.8 (packaged with our Linux distro), though we wouldn't rule out upgrading to a newer version if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an acl based on src for the ip ranges and then use a new backend for that acl.

Should be straight forward and exact syntax is covered in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! It now seems kind of obvious reading the ACL part of the docs.